# Google .NET CloudCredential sample?

Tags: .net, google-cloud-platform, iaas

I am trying to figure out how to programmatically interact with Google IaaS using the .NET API, but I'm a bit lost.  The sample code doesn't work with `ComputeCredential` at all, and the source doesn't really make it clear to me.  I see a bug request asking to create a `ComputeCredential` from a `ServiceAccountCredential` which would work great if I could, because I have code working against Storage using a `ServiceAccountCredential`, but I can't figure out how to get to a `ComputeCredential` at all.

Can someone briefly show me how to create a `ComputeCredential` properly and use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I could do this with a `ServiceAccountCredential` just like storage:

```
var service = new ComputeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "cleaner"
});
```

I'm not clear on why `ComputeCredential` even exists at this point to be honest.